# Reading a BigTIFF file in R

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff, soilgrids

I am trying to load a BigTIFF file into R, so that I can extract some data from a set of coordinates. The file I am working with can be found here: ftp://ftp.soilgrids.org/data/recent/CLYPPT_M_sl3_250m_ll.tif

I generally load rasters and extract points using the following code:

```
require(raster)
require(rgdal)
require(sp)

#some sample lat lon for extracting data
points <- structure(c(-89.426, -89.441, -72.18, 43.046, 43.038, 42.48), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("longitude", "latitude")))

#load a raster layer
layer <- raster('/path/to/raster.tif')

#extract data from the layer for the points of interest.
output <- extract(layer, points)
```

When I run this code with the raster linked above I receive the following error:

```
/fs/data3/caverill/SoilGrids/CLYPPT_M_sl4_250m_ll.tif: This is a BigTIFF file.
  This format not supported by this version of libtiff..
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Please describe it in more detail.

Comment: added detail about why my usual code doesn't work in this case.

Comment: That's a pretty clear error message - you need a raster package that links to a GDAL that uses a libtiff that has BigTIFF support. What's your operating system? You'll probably have to build something from source code...

Comment: @Spacedman I feel that. Its more of how to implement this in R.

Comment: Its not a simple procedure, and requires a lot of steps, and very dependent on your operating system.